# Query to retrieve x number of rows based on quantity from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Edit: I'm using SQL Server 2014

I need to write a query to return only the number of rows where the sum of the quantity covers a quantity from a different table.

I'm working with two tables. An inventory table and a purchase history table. I want to return the rows from the purchase history table for a specific inventory item where the sum of the quantities in said rows covers the quantity on hand from the inventory table, ordered by newest purchase date to oldest.

Example:
Inventory table

```
-------------------
| SKU  | Quantity |
-------------------
| 1234 | 10       |
-------------------
```

Purchase history table

```
--------------------------------
| SKU  | Quantity | Date       |
--------------------------------
| 1234 | 5        | 2019-01-01 |
| 1234 | 3        | 2018-12-01 |
| 1234 | 9        | 2018-11-01 |
| 1234 | 4        | 2018-10-01 |
| 1234 | 12       | 2018-09-01 |
--------------------------------
```

This is the result I'm expecting

```
--------------------------------
| SKU  | Quantity | Date       |
--------------------------------
| 1234 | 5        | 2019-01-01 |
| 1234 | 3        | 2018-12-01 |
| 1234 | 9        | 2018-11-01 |
--------------------------------
```

Because 5 + 3 + 9 covers the 10 we have in stock.

Maybe I'm missing something simple, but I just can't think of how to get the results to stop at, in this specific case, the third record.

Also, I would really prefer to avoid using loops, if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, because I just can't wrap my head around this one.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You will need a running total to solve. The solution to this varies greatly on the version of sql server you are using. Which version are you using?

Comment: I updated my question to say which version I'm using. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Select B.* 
 From  Inventory A
 Cross Apply ( 
               Select *
                From  (
                      Select *,RB = sum([Quantity]) over (Partition By SKU Order by Date Desc) - Quantity
                       From  Purchase 
                       Where SKU=A.SKU
                      ) B1
                Where RB<=A.Quantity 
              ) B
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably do something like the following (untested):

```
SELECT ph.sku, ph.quantity, ph.date
FROM
(SELECT 
 purchasehistory.*, 
 SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as tquantity
FROM purchasehistory) ph inner join inventory i
 on ph.sku = i.sku
WHERE
 ph.tquantity <= i.quantity
```

The idea here is to calculate the running sum in the inner query, then join with your inventory table. I've made an assumption with the ORDER BY date, but you could adjust that.

Edit: So based on the comment that you want the first N rows that use all your inventory (as opposed to the first N rows that don't exceed your inventory) I think you could do something like:

```
SELECT ph.sku, ph.quantity, ph.date
FROM
(SELECT 
 purchasehistory.*, 
 SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as tquantity
FROM purchasehistory) ph inner join inventory i
 on ph.sku = i.sku
WHERE
 ph.tquantity < i.quantity
```

This is the same basic idea but the running sum is switched to only count previous rows (not include the current row) and the join uses < rather than <=. That way if the previous rows quantity didn't total to inventory yet, you will include the next row (even if that total now exceeds inventory).

Comment: This got me very, very close. The SKU I'm looking at has 10 in inventory and the purchase history record I'm expecting has 12. That 12 would cover the 10 just fine. But ph.tquantity <= i.quantity is filtering it out.  I'm not sure what other conditional would work there.

Comment: I've added another version to the answer now that I think I understand the question better.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with an INNER JOIN

when summing the rows, I use IIF to set the current row to zero in the sum, because I don't want to include that in the check

```
begin try drop table #Phistory end try begin catch end catch;
begin try drop table #inventory  end try begin catch end catch;
SELECT 1234 SKU,5 Quantity, cast('20190101' as date) [date] into #Phistory;
INSERT #Phistory (SKU, Quantity,[date]) VALUES (1234,3,'20181201'), (1234,9,'20181101'),(1234,4,'20181001'),(1234,12,'20180901'),(1235,3,'20181201'), (1235,9,'20181101'),(1235,4,'20181001'),(1235,12,'20180901'),(1235,500,'20180801'),(1235,50,'20180601');
select  1234 SKU, 10 quantity into #inventory;
insert #inventory values(1235,99);

SELECT p1.SKU, 
        p1.Quantity, 
        p1.[Date],
        SUM(p2.quantity) RunningTotal
                FROM #Phistory p1 
                    JOIN #PHistory p2 
                        ON p1.SKU = p2.sku and p2.date >= p1.date
                        GROUP BY p1.SKU, 
                                p1.Quantity, 
                                p1.[Date]
                        HAVING SUM(IIF(p1.date = p2.date , 0 , p2.quantity)) 
                                 <= (SELECT inv.quantity from #inventory inv where inv.sku = p1.sku) 
                        order by p1.sku,p1.date DESC;
```